# Doxygen not producing correct inheritance structure when using codeblocks 13.12

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am trying to get this simple class structure in c++ below to produce the correct doxygen html files.  I am using codeblocks 13.12's extract documentation to produce the doxyfile. Than I am using the doxywizard feature in codeblocks to call macport's doxygen version 1.8.7. Every time I produce a doxygen html output the new_instance method in class rider is missing. Is there a way to fix this? Am i doing something wrong?

```
class cowboy /** a class to store and utilize horses */
{
public:
    virtual ~cowboy() {}

    int horse; /**< an integer that counts the number of horses the cowboy owns */

    /** @brief prints the number of horses
     *
     */
    void print()
    {
        std::cout<< "I ride a horse and own " << horse << " horses.\n";
    }

    /** \brief creates a new instance of cowboy
     *
     * \return cowboy* the location the new instance of cowboy is stored
     *
     */
    virtual cowboy* new_instance() //operates with factory
    {
        return new cowboy;
    }
};

class rider: public cowboy /**an object that also owns horses but is not as cool as a cowboy  */
{
     /** @brief creates a new instance of rider as a cowboy pointer
     *
     * @return cowboy* the location the new instance of rider is stored
     *
     */
    cowboy* new_instance()
    {
        return new rider;
    }
};
```

Additional information that may be helpful. The version of codeblocks I have is the 32 bit application you can download directly from codeblocks' website. The OS is Mountain Lion just in case this problem is specific to that version of the os.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem is caused by putting an inheritance structure in the same file. I am not sure if it matters if its a .h file or a .cpp file. In my case I was using a .cpp file. The problem is doxygen is not recognizing new_instance as a reimplementation in the above code when placed in the same file. Additionally if you delete new_instance from cowboy, the new_instance in rider still does not show up in the doxygen created html file. To fix the issue each class needs to be split up into .h/.cpp files. After the split the doxygen created html file works correctly.